# How to make chromium browser look nativein KDE

Tags: gui, chromium

I am trying to make chromium browser look nativein KDE, and I have 
followed instructions from [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/making-chrome-look-native-in-kubuntu).
Everything looks ok except there is a line under the title bar. 
Anyone knows how to eliminate it? Thanks!

Here is the browser and system version info:

Version 29.0.1547.65 Kubuntu 13.10 (29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2)
[image]

Comment: That link is from 2010. Maybe things have changed since then? Plus, it's for Google Chrome. You mention Chromium. It's just possible that some differences exist.

Answer (score 1):

The missing thing is to set the gtk widget style to oxygen-gtk.
I found [this](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=92866) tutorial more detailed.